# Heat capacity for real insulator

Tags: solid-state-physics, insulators

In the Debye model, for temperatures $T \ll T_D \equiv \frac{\hbar\omega_D}{k_B}$, the molar heat capacity $c_V$ can be calculated as follows:
$$c_V = \frac{12\pi^{4}}{5}R \left(\frac{T}{T_D}\right)^3$$
(where $12\pi^{4}/5\approx 234$).

Now if we take the limit $T\rightarrow 0$, we would expect from the Debye-model $c_V = 0$. However, this is apparently not the case for a real insulator, where I think we get $c_V = \alpha$, with $\alpha$ being a constant, in the limit $T\rightarrow 0$.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: You do not explain why you think $c_v$ is a constant. Do you assume equipartition? That is classical physics, not valid at low $T$.

Answer (score 1):

The heat capacity does not go to a constant value at small temperatures.

The Third Law of Thermodynamics states that the heat capacity of any substance $c_{V}$ approaches $0$ as $T\rightarrow0$.  The Debye model correctly predicts this.  Moreover, it also gives the correct rate at which $c_{V}\rightarrow0$.  Previously, the [Einstein model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid) had correctly predicted that $c_{V}\rightarrow0$ as $T\rightarrow0$, but $c_{V}$ vanished much more rapidly in the Einstein model than in real solids.  Debye corrected that expression to get a numerically accurate expression for the low-temperature heat capacity of lattice solids.